# Should I create a separate Campaign for each product I offer or should I keep them inside one Campaign?

Tags: google-ads, campaigns

AdWords help needed:
Should I:
1) create separate CAMPAIGNS for each product and AD GROUPS with variations of different match types and keywords in it? This means few AD GROUPS but many CAMPAIGNS.
or
2) create one CAMPAIGN and place all products along with variations of keywords inside in separate AD GROUPS? This means dozens of AD GROUPS in one CAMPAIGN.

What's the best practice?

To be precise, I offer some [AV equipment for hire (rent)](https://www.avehire.co.uk/av-equipment-hire). I have quite many different categories. Currently I keep them all in one Campaign and created Ad Groups for each product.

Now, I want to differentiate them by creating separate Ad Groups for words "hire" and separate for words "rental". All this to be more relevant in terms of Ads.

Another thing is - should I separate mobile CAMPAIGNS from desktop ones? Or should I keep both devices in the same CAMPAIGN but in different AD GROUPS, or do not differentiate mobile devices from desktops at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Campaign vs Ad Group: Both would work fine as at ad group level you will have the specific keyword(s) and ad.

The general recommendation is to create campaign/ad group based on website structure. Meaning a campaign can have several ad groups.

So, either can work for you.

But, if you will have too many campaigns and specific ad group in each, would give you the option to control the budget very effectively. Meaning higher performing campaign can have its own budget and also greater level control without disturbing other ad groups. But you also need to realise if you will have way too many campaigns then managing might be difficult.

The rough recommendation would be, have few campaigns and few ad groups in each, again you need to think about your business and website in detail. This is a rough guide only.

Mobile / Desktop: In the initial stage you can keep in the same and you may bid a bit higher for mobile if you feel there would have more conversion for mobile which is true in general.

Comment: Thank you for advice @TopQnA. I came into similar conclusion. Now I'm sure I know what to do. Thanks